# Why I get DllNotFoundException when dll present in build output catalog?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I ve got two projects in my solution: one is a console application, and another is a unit test project. Both of which reference third project which is a class library which is build as AnyCPU. This library uses native library through pinvoke. I get DllNotFoundException when running unit tests. Console application works well. I guess the problem is that native library is x86, console application is x86, unit tests project is x86 (build), but the test executable isn't x86. How do I check it. Native library is present in both console application and unit test project output directories.

Comment: may be your native Dll has a dependency on another native dll

Comment: no, the problem is that unit test executable can't catch library

Comment: Sure, unlike your console exe, your test runner exe is located elsewhere.  More than one way to solve this problem, simplest way is to assign Environment.CurrentDirectory in your test setup code.